# How do visual studio 2013 data compare tool for Windows Azure?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, sitefinity

Related : Visual Studio 2013 (Professional Edition)

I am trying to create Data Migration Script to deploy the changes on Staging Server.
This works locally fine. But When I try to run the generated Script on Azure Database, I get TextPtr is not supported on Azure platform. I studied more about it & found that the newer editions of SQL Server (sply for Windows Azure (SQL 2014 may be)) has dropped some keywords/functionalities the list can be [found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336248.aspx).

**The Sql Database Project only provides the Schema Compare, but Data Compare is avilables in tools Section (*where we can not set Target Project Type property*).**

I wonder how can I deploy/Migrate the changes made in one environment to another in such a Situation. Currently I had to overwrite the existing Database on Azure platform.

But this is not Identical also, for first time this could work but not for later, as there could be some changes made to the Staging or other environments.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, when trying to migrate between a test and staging environment in Azure. As a quick fix, I got around the problem by just doing a "copy" of the dev database via the Azure dashboard. [image: Azure Dashboard screenshot]